# Please help identify subject/noun/verbs?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, infinitive-vs-gerund

Can anyone help me to identify what the subject, nouns, and verbs are in this sentence?

> Recognizing and pursuing only your interests results in a selfish, collapsing world order.

Answer (score 5):

> Recognizing and pursuing only your interests results in a selfish, collapsing world order.

At the most basic level, this sentence has a very simple structure:

> [Subject] [verbs] [object].

But the subject, verb, and object are each composed of multiple words, which makes it rather tricky!

Let's start with the verb. The sentence is in the present tense, so we can tell that the verb is the one in the middle with an `s` on the end of it: *results*. In fact it is the [prepositional verb](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Prepositions-with-Verbs.htm) *results **in***.

The object is the thing that comes after the verb: *an order*. This object, which is of course a noun, has an adjective attached: *a **world** order*. And this [compound noun](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Compound-Nouns.htm) "world order" is *itself* modified by two additional adjectives to form the complete [noun phrase](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Noun-Phrases.htm): *a **selfish, collapsing** world order.*

The only thing left in the sentence is the subject, and this subject is especially complicated. The subject must be a noun, and in this case the subject is two nouns taken together: *recognizing and pursuing*. These are **gerunds**. A gerund is a thing that describes an action; of course usually we call that kind of word a "verb," but a gerund is a verb that is used *as a noun* to refer to the action in general instead of referring to a specific instance of that action happening. For this reason gerunds are sometimes called *verbal nouns*.

As it happens, the verbs that form the base of these gerunds—*to recognize* and *to pursue*—are both transitive verbs. Therefore we need an object that will belong to the two verbal nouns: *interests*. This noun is modified by an adjective: ***your** interests*. And just like in the main object, the compound noun is modified yet again: ***only** your interests*.

So we have a very simple sentence made up of pretty complex parts:

- *Subject*: Recognizing and pursuing only your interests
- *Verb*: results in
- *Object*: a selfish, collapsing world order.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been very informative.

Comment: Nicely done!  I think one other thing that makes this sentence especially tricky for the learner is that *results* can be either a noun or a verb!

Comment: Randomhead, I find multiple issues with this answer. First you should have made a distinction between a function and category, rather you mixed it up. Verb though sometimes used for both function and category, it is better to use Predicator for the function the verb does here. The word "world" is never an adjective, rather it is a noun used as an attributive modifier of the head in Noun Phrase structure. It is not always correct that a subject has to have a Noun Phrase. In here *recognising* and *persuing* are not noun, they are actually a verb.

Comment: @Man_From_India You're wrong or unhelpful on every point. Please either try harder, or don't try so hard. You use the words "function" and "category" that don't appear in the question. What do you mean? I don't know what a "Predicator" is, so probably Kristin doesn't either. The word "world" is an adjective [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/world). An expression like "attributive modifier of the head noun in Noun Phrase structure" is a useless thing to say to a student. "Adjective" is a much nicer thing to say, even if it were a mere compound noun. Gerunds are nouns.

Comment: And here the subject is realised by a non finite clause.

Comment: @gotube no argument with MW, but here "world order" is just like "ice cream", structurally. Dictionaries should not be trusted for grammatical categories. And adjective is a category and attractive modifier is a function. When you are talking about a subject, you are talking about a function. When you are talking about a noun your are talking about a category. My point is never mix them, though the term verb is often used to mean both a category and a function, it is not advisable to reserve the term verb for category and predicator for function.

Comment: Another point about the answer I didn't like is *VERB - result in*. Verb is *result* and *in* is a preposition.

Comment: @Man_From_India I trust a dictionary like Merriam-Webster, and yes, even thefreedictionary.com before I trust some random person on the Internet making big claims with no cited authorities.

Comment: @gotube I am not asking you to trust dictionaries, they are to be trusted only for meaning, that is their primary goal. For grammatical categories, they are not to be trusted 100%. For example I once wrote an answer where I mentioned that "six" is not an adjective, it's a determinative. In dictionaries, you will find that "six" is an adjective and a determiner. Now again modern grammar books will object the use of 'determiner' as a category.

Comment: See my previous comment. I'm done

Comment: @gotube "near" is a preposition. Check online dictionaries where you will find no dictionaries tells you that it is a preposition. At least it was like this when I had this confusion like you, probably 5-6 years back. But there is a dictionary that says it is a preposition, it is OED which I don't have access.