# Gerund POS classification

Tags: verbs, gerunds, parts-of-speech, present-participles

Following up on my previous [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345094/proper-use-of-ing-to-in-the-beginning-of-a-sentence/345102?noredirect=1#comment667655_345102) I am trying to find the proper parts of speech (POS) Tag for "Hiking interest rates" and "Cutting interest rates" in the context of the following sentence, part of [this](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/08/10/investing/premarket-stocks-trading-stagflation/index.html) article:

> Hiking interest rates to get inflation under control when unemployment
> is rising could push unemployment even higher. Cutting interest rates
> to stimulate the economy could produce more inflation.

From what I have read, the -ing can be tagged into Verb, Adjectives or Nouns, depending on the use. I have followed the advice given in my previous question and as per the website [IELTS Online Tests](https://ieltsonlinetests.com/ielts-grammar/gerund-subject):

> Definition: A gerund subject is a verb form that functions as a noun and acts as the subject of a sentence.

However, it also confuses me that it could work as an adjective modifying the noun "interest rates" because they are increasing/dropping (as per the [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/adjectives-ending-ed-ing#:%7E:text=%2Ding%20adjectives,It%27s%20really%20frightening.) website):

> Adjectives that end in -ing generally describe the thing that causes the emotion

Therefore, in the context of POS what would be the correct classification for "Hiking interest rates" and "Cutting interest rates"?

Comment: "Hiking interest rates" and "Cutting interest rates" are both gerund-participial clauses, (i.e. non-finite clauses) each consisting of a gerund participle verb + a noun phrase direct object. They are part of the subjects "Hiking interest rates to get inflation under control when unemployment is rising" and "Cutting interest rates to stimulate the economy".

Comment: Note: I would strongly advise you not to call such clauses nouns, or noun phrases; they are not. The classification of non-finite subordinate clauses is based on the classification of their head verb (gerund participle / past participle etc.) rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: Note also that in each of the subjects, the infinitival clause is functioning as a purpose adjunct, leaving "hiking interest rates" and "cutting interest rates" as the core parts of the subjects.

Comment: Well, I don't think they are clauses.

Comment: My answer would be identical to the one I gave in the linked question.  These are participle clauses that function as the subject (or part of the subject) of the sentence.  I think this is a duplicate of the linked question.  Shall I vote to close it?

Comment: "Functions as a noun" confuses **grammatical functions** with **parts of speech**. **Syntactic constituents** get **syntactic roles** — that is, they get **grammatical functions** — not **parts of speech** like individual words do. So no phrase can "function" as a "noun", because "noun" is ɴᴏᴛ a function; rather, it's a part of speech, which is different from a function. Phrases, including clauses, can only function as subject, objects, complements,  modifiers, etc.